# Mapsforge rewrite : Context menu on longpress on Map

Tags: android, contextmenu, openstreetmap, long-press

I am using mapsforge library to use maps in my app. I need to fire up a context menu and return the map coordinates. Here's what i have tried. In my layout i have a hidden button set up below the mapview that listens for longpress.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <org.mapsforge.map.android.view.MapView
            android:id="@+id/offlinemapview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mapview_btn_offline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then i am registering this button for context menu and inflate the context menu.

```
mapb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapview_btn_offline);
registerForContextMenu(mapb);

  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.map_menu, menu);
    }
```

But when i run the app, even after the longpress the context menu does not show up. Any ideas on how to get this working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually mapview class is an extended class from ViewGroup. 
you should do following:

1.Override the OnTouchEvent in mapsforge. MotionEvent gets you some actions. 
2.Define a timer to hold the time between touch_down and touch_up or cancel.
3.It's up to you to how implement the spare parts...

Comment: thank you, i implemented the onLongPress from simpleGestureListener. I am now trying to get the map geo-cordinates of the long pressed place.

Comment: can we have a snippet for it? I also need this code..... I hope mapsforge will support this on future versions

Comment: There is now support for longpress in all three (rescue, rewrite, stable) versions of mapsforge.